# How can i find sum of three element in a given away

Tags: dart

Is there a method we use to reach the desired number in an array given in dart language.. I can do this for binary ones, but I can't do it for a code that finds the sum of 3 or more elements

For example

```
Input: candidates = [10,1,2,7,6,1,5], target = 8
Output: 
[
[1,1,6],
[1,2,5],
[1,7],
[2,6]
]
```

this is the my code i have done until now

```
void main() {
  var candidates = [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5], target = 8;
  var answer = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < candidates.length; j++) {
      if (candidates[i] + candidates[j] == target && i != j && i < j) {
        answer.add([candidates[i], candidates[j]]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This question looks a lot like some assignment you got from a school or company. Could you please show us what you have done to solve this problem yourself and we can then provide some input to how you can improve your solution or point out where your problem is.

Comment: no this is not a school assignment this is a question from leetcode

Comment: Another note, remember to accept answers if they answer your question. I can see you have multiple questions here on the Dart tag with very detailed answers but with no accepted answer or comment about what the answer is missing from being accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I could not know. how can I accept the answer? I will respond to all of them now

Comment: There should be a button at an answer where you can click "Accept" or something.

Comment: ok thankyou i will do it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241381/discussion-between-yunus-kocatas-and-julemand101).

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be done more efficient but since the solution is for some Leetcode assignment, I don't really want to spend too much time on optimizations.

I have tried added some comments in the code which explains my way of doing it:

```
void main() {
  getSumLists([10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5], 8).forEach(print);
  // [5, 1, 2]
  // [1, 6, 1]
  // [1, 7]
  // [6, 2]

  getSumLists([2, 5, 2, 1, 2], 5).forEach(print);
  // [2, 1, 2]
  // [5]
}

Iterable<List<int>> getSumLists(
  List<int> candidates,
  int target, {
  List<int>? tempAnswer,
  int sum = 0,
}) sync* {
  // We cannot use default value in parameter since that makes list const
  final tempAnswerNullChecked = tempAnswer ?? [];

  if (sum == target) {
    // We got a result we can return.
    // OPTIMIZATION: If you know the returned list from each found result is not
    // being used between found results, you can remove the `.toList()` part.
    yield tempAnswerNullChecked.toList();
  } else if (sum > target) {
    // No need to search further in this branch since we are over the target
    return;
  }

  // Make a copy so we don't destroy the input list but also so it works even
  // if provided list as input is non-growing / non-modifiable
  final newCandidates = candidates.toList();

  while (newCandidates.isNotEmpty) {
    // We take numbers from the end of the list since that is more efficient.
    final number = newCandidates.removeLast();

    // Recursive call where we return all results we are going to find given
    // the new parameters
    yield* getSumLists(
      newCandidates,
      target,
      tempAnswer: tempAnswerNullChecked..add(number),
      sum: sum + number,
    );

    // Instead of creating a new tempAnswerNullChecked, we just reuse it and
    // make sure we remove any value we are temporary adding
    tempAnswerNullChecked.removeLast();

    // Ensure we don't get duplicate combinations. So if we have checked the
    // number `1` we remove all `1` so we don't try the second `1`.
    newCandidates.removeWhere((element) => element == number);
  }
}
```